# Authentication Bypass Using SQL Injection

Tags: asp.net, .net

When making a security scan this error is shown as a high :

```
Remediation Tasks: Filter out hazardous characters from user input ?
for parameter (Parameter = txtPassword),(Parameter = btnLogin) and (Parameter = txtName)
```

all of them is used in code like here:

```
With sqlcomm.Parameters
   .AddWithValue("@userName", DataEncryption.DataEncryption.EncryptString(LCase(txtName.Text), "OmSs23re24&&UsErNa(Me"))
   .AddWithValue("@Pass", DataEncryption.DataEncryption.EncryptString(txtPassword.Text, "OmSP12aSsW%%8oR*d"))
End With

If (Session("Admin") Is Nothing) Then
    If txtName.Text = txtPassword.Text Or forgotpassCls.GetUserLoginFlag(Session("custid").ToString()) Then
       If ForceChange = "True" Then
            Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx", True)
       Else
            Response.Redirect(DefaultURL, True)
       End If
    End If
 Else '' if the user is an admin
     If txtName.Text = txtPassword.Text Or forgotpassCls.GetUserLoginFlag(Session("Admin").ToString()) Then
         If ForceChange = "True" Then
              Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx", True)
          Else
               Response.Redirect(DefaultURL, True)
          End If
      End If
 End If
```

What can I do?

Comment: Assuming (as it seems here) that you always use parameters in your VB code, and whatever SQL receives these parameters doesn't use them to construct any dynamic SQL, then you've already done a great deal to prevent SQL injection - and there aren't any "hazardous characters" to filter out.

Comment: From what you have posted, there does not appear to be any security issues.  You will need to find out what it is really complaining about.  It's possible it flagged your code incorrectly, or you are using those values somewhere else that you didn't post.

Comment: On second thought, are you displaying the username and or password on the page for any reason? Like if you submit a username but no password?  It is possible it is flagging that as a security issue if you aren't correctly encoding the user input before displaying it on the page, which could lead to a XSS problem. Allowing one site to inject javascript, etc by redirecting someone to your site, but have your site inject javascript of their choosing into your own page.  That javascript could for example, capture key presses, or change your login form to post to their site so they can see it.