# Authentication Bypass Using SQL Injection appScan

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

### when making a security scan this error is shown as a high :

### Remediation Tasks: Filter out hazardous characters from user input ?

for parameter (Parameter = txtPassword),(Parameter = btnLogin) and (Parameter = txtName)
all of them is used in code like here:

```
---------------

With sqlcomm.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@userName", DataEncryption.DataEncryption.EncryptString(LCase(txtName.Text), "OmSs23re24&&UsErNa(Me"))
            .AddWithValue("@Pass", DataEncryption.DataEncryption.EncryptString(txtPassword.Text, "OmSP12aSsW%%8oR*d"))
  End With


If (Session("Admin") Is Nothing) Then
                    If txtName.Text = txtPassword.Text Or forgotpassCls.GetUserLoginFlag(Session("custid").ToString()) Then
                        If ForceChange = "True" Then
                            Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx", True)
                        Else
                            Response.Redirect(DefaultURL, True)
                        End If


                    End If
                Else '' if the user is an admin
                    If txtName.Text = txtPassword.Text Or forgotpassCls.GetUserLoginFlag(Session("Admin").ToString()) Then
                        If ForceChange = "True" Then
                            Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx", True)
                        Else
                            Response.Redirect(DefaultURL, True)
                        End If


                    End If
                End If
```

what i can do please help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication Bypass Using SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716929/authentication-bypass-using-sql-injection)

Comment: Don't re-post your questions. If you have edits to make (but I can't see any obvious ones), please do so to your original question.

Comment: Definite dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716929/authentication-bypass-using-sql-injection?rq=1